# How to un-split VScode terminals (tabs)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Per [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-splitting), we can split **Visual Studio Code**'s terminal into tabs by keyboard shortcut `CTRL+SHIFT+5`.
[image]

But, if we want to remove one of the added pane, how to do that?

1. remove last pane ?
2. remove first (or even the "in-between" tabs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the trash icon next to the drop-down, it will remove the active pane leaving the other ones alone[image]

Comment: thanks, found too at this moment  :) , however, it deletes the right-most one, what if we want to delete first or even the "in-between" tabs...

Comment: @T.Todua that's what I thought too but reading the tool-tip on the trash button, I found out it actually removes the *active* one

Comment: Too bad we have to close one terminal to unsplit the things :-(